# How to display parsed data from ajax in express.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, ejs

I have this page made using node.js + express where I am displaying the following table :
[image]

I wish to reload only the table with new data using ajax when limit is changed using the dropdown (one with the label show result), but am having trouble doing so.
Here's the ejs code that displays my table :

```
 <table class="assignment-table table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-responsive">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>S.No.</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Subject</th>
                                <th>Topic</th>
                                <th>Faculty</th>
                                <th>Posted</th>
                                <th>Last Date</th>
                                <th>Mode of Submission</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="table_body">

                            <% for(var i =0;i< result.length;i++) { %>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="result_id">
                                    <a target="_blank" href="/assignment/abc.pdf" class="download-link" id="">
                                            <%= result[i]._id %>
                                        </a>
                                </td>

                                <td class="result_name">
                                    <a target="_blank" href="/assignment/abc.pdf" class="download-link">
                                             <%=  result[i].nameAssignment %> 
                                        </a>
                                </td>
                                <td class="result_subject">
                                    <a target="_blank" href="/assignment/abc.pdf" class="download-link">
                                            <%= result[i].Subject %>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td class="result_topic">
                                    <a target="_blank" href="/assignment/abc.pdf" class="download-link">
                                           <%= result[i].Topic %>
                                        </a>
                                </td>
                                <td class="result_faculty">
                                    <a target="_blank" href="/assignment/abc.pdf" class="download-link">
                                        <%= result[i].Faculty %></a>
                                </td>
                                <td class="result_posted">
                                    <a target="_blank" href="/assignment/abc.pdf" class="download-link">
                                        <%= result[i].Posted %></a>
                                </td>
                                <td class="result_lastdate">
                                    <a target="_blank" href="/assignment/abc.pdf" class="download-link">
                                        <%= result[i].LastDate %></a>
                                </td>
                                <td class="result_submission">
                                    <a target="_blank" href="/assignment/abc.pdf" class="download-link">
                                        <%= result[i].Submission %></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <% } %>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

In the **filter_result()** route mentioned above, I am fetching limit from the url and querying the database with new limits and rendering the page again.

```
   Router.get('/filter_result',(req,res) => {
    limit = parseInt( decodeURIComponent(req.query.limit) );
    models.filterResults(limit, (count,result) =>  {
        //if (err) throw err;
        console.log(limit);
        //res.send(result);
        res.render('assignment-list',{limit:limit,result:result,count : count});
    }); 
});
```

How can I redisplay the table in the ejs page?

Comment: So does `res.render('assignment-list')` response HTML?

Comment: yeah, it renders the view page displaying whatever HTML is written in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your `.ejs` format is rendered only once when you load or reload the page. So what you do is re-render (or, replace) the HTML from your AJAX call on top of already-rendered HTML.

It seems that you're using jQuery already so my example code uses jQuery too.

Re-rendering (or, again, replacing) HTML depends on what your `/filter_result` responds. If it's just bunch of `<tr>`s then it might be

#### JS

```
$('table.assignment-table').find('tbody').html(result);
```

If it's the entire `<table>` then you'd better wrap `<table>` with some wrapper like `<div>` and do the following.

#### HTML

```
<div id="table-wrapper">
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
$('div#table-wrapper').html(result);
```

How you refer your wrapper and replace the content can vary.

## Update 1

Assuming your API (`/filter_result`) returns an array of assignment objects like

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "Subject": "Your subject",
      "Topic": "Your topic",
      ...
    },
    ...

  ]
}
```

you can create bunch of `<tr/>`s from data and replace the existing `<tr/>`s with them like (with jQuery of course. About creating DOM with jQuery, you can refer [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes).)

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'URL_TO_FILTER_RESULT',
  data: SOME_DATA,
  success: function(res) {
    var assignments = res.data;
    var body = [];

    assignments.forEach(function(assignment) {
      var tr = $('<tr/>');
      tr.append($('<td/>').html('<a href="blah-blah">' + assignment.Subject + '</a>');
      tr.append($('<td/>').html('<a href="blah-blah">' + assignment.Topic + '</a>');

      ...

      body.push(tr);
    });

    $('table.assignment-table').find('tbody').html(body);
  }
})
```

Comment: My current /filter_result route returns objects from the database. So is there any way to display them as it is? Or do I need to change my function so as to return the values as you suggested earlier?

Comment: @Anshul That really depends on how you implement your API and client, but the preferred way is to design your API to return JSON objects, and your client to create DOMs itself.